# Excel Help: Create Variable based On Number of Instances

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I've IDs in column A that I would like to split into 5 equal groups for each ID. I have applied this formula which does a great job of splitting the IDs into 5 equal groups in column B.

```
=CEILING((ROW()-ROW($A$2)+1) / CEILING((ROW($A$88)-ROW($A$2)+1)/5,1),1)
```

The problem is, that in the Cell $A$2 and $A$88 has similar ID = 1.

I'm hoping there's a kind soul out there can modify this formula so I can make it so the 5 equal groups are split for each ID for the entire column, rather than hard stops for each ID.

[image]

Comment: Can you show an example with different IDs?  I can't tell why some IDs have 1 in the Bin column and some have 2, given that all the IDs are 1

Comment: The current worksheet shows only 1s as ID, could you show us a bit larger Data Range, and what I've realized that, you have IDs and you want to club them in 5 groups in the Column only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is bears some similarity to your other question, and using `CEILING()` is a great idea.

Your formula has two terms that you need to generalize, rather than be hard coded:

1. The total number of rows for the current ID.  This is easy:

`=COUNTIF(A:A,A2)`

2. The count of the current number of rows of the current ID as the formula is filled down.  This is done using an "expanding" range:

`=COUNTIF(A$2:A2,A2)`

Incorporating these two expressions into your formula gives:

`=CEILING((COUNTIF(A$2:A2,A2)/CEILING(COUNTIF(A:A,A2)/5,1)),1)`

You added 1 to the row counts in your formula, and you can adjust this formula similarly if you need to.

I hope this helps, and good luck.

Answer (score -1):

*This simple Formula can also generate the list of IDs in BIN Column with increment after every 7th Row.*

```
=INT(((ROW(A1)-1)/7))*1+1
```

Or even this improvised Formula will also generate the list of IDs in similar order.

```
=CEILING(COUNTIF(A$2:A2,A2)/7,1)
```

**In the OP's &  @Bandersnatch Formula for increment, value is divided by 5 but as result the IDs are incrementing after every 7th Row. It's the only reason I've divided it by 7 and the significance is if you want to change the sequence of INCREMENT simply replace 7 with the required number.**

**NB:** In the screen shot attached with the OP, shows that the IDs are incrementing in BIN Column after 18th Row. So if you need to alter the INCREMENT, simply you need to replace 7 with 18, and your Formula will be, `=INT(((ROW(A1)-1)/18))*1+1`.

**Also,** in OP you have written, *"The problem is, that in the Cell $A$2 and $A$88 has similar ID = 1"*.

**To solve this problem you can just Sort the ID Column so all 1s will be in the first group.**

*I do hope this help you and others too.*